# Playing Video Rips Using Windows Media Center

Tags: video, windows-media-center, ripping

How do I play H264/XVid rips using Windows Media Center?

Answer (score 3):

I'd vote for the [CCCP](http://www.cccp-project.net/) codec pack.  But K-Lite is good.  Make sure to let the installation register the codecs with Media Player/Center and you should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

I just upgraded my divx to version 7.  It supports H264 and Media Center is able to use the codec natively:

http://www.divx.com

Answer (score 1):

You need to download a Codec pack like this one

http://www.free-codecs.com/download/K_Lite_Codec_Pack.htm

A google search for Codec Pack will provide you with more options.